# Amazon S3 - Where we need to store Access and Secret Keys?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3 and would like to know where we need to store the Access and Secret Keys. Actually I am using ASP.Net app so can I store these Keys in Web.config or which is the better practice to store these keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web.config is probably the most common place to store them, as appKeys.   If you want to protect them a bit better, [encrypt the configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) where they're stored.